# разместить section между блоками nav и aside

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать так:

[image: эталонный вид]

но получается только так:

[image: мой результат]

Код:

```css
body 
{
background-color: darkslategray;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 10px; 
}

header
{
display: block;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: gray;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
}
nav 
{
width: 25%;
float: left; 
background-color: gray;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
}
aside 
{
width: 25%;
float: right; 
background-color: gray;   
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
}

section 
{
width: 45%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;'
background-color: gray;   
}

footer
{
clear: both;    
color: white;
background-color: gray;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="secondstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
заголовок
</header>
<nav>
навигация
</nav>
<section>
<header>
    заголовок секции
</header>
<article>
    Текст артикля
</article>
<footer>
    Нижняя часть артикля
</footer>
</section>
<aside>
асайд
</aside>
<footer>
футер сайта
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте flexы, и проблем не будет. [Ссылка на ресурс по флексам](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)

Ну а в вашем случае, вы просто не учитываете margin и padding

```css
body 
{
background-color: darkslategray;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 10px; 
}

header
{
display: block;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: gray;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
}
nav 
{
width: calc( 25% - 20px); /*Берем в учет margin*/
box-sizing: border-box; /*padding перестают увеличивать размер блока*/
float: left; 
background-color: gray;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
}
aside 
{
width: calc( 25% - 20px); /*Берем в учет margin*/
box-sizing: border-box; /*padding перестают увеличивать размер блока*/
float: right; 
background-color: gray;   
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
}

section 
{
width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;'
background-color: gray;   
}

footer
{
clear: both;    
color: white;
background-color: gray;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="secondstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
заголовок
</header>
<nav>
навигация
</nav>
<section>
<header>
    заголовок секции
</header>
<article>
    Текст артикля
</article>
<footer>
    Нижняя часть артикля
</footer>
</section>
<aside>
асайд
</aside>
<footer>
футер сайта
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```